# Define or Derive the Double integral for Area in the Complex

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Recently I was in a collaboration forum and others discussed using some type of double integral formula to derive the area of the image of a function. We have a holomorphic, injective function under consideration whose preimage is the unit disc and maps 0 to 1. Can someone please explain how this integral $\int\int_D|f’|dxdy $ I saw others write for evaluating the proposed area Is derived? This isn’t defined or derived anywhere in our textbook. Please be detailed because my calculus familiarity is not that high - it’s been years since I took those classes. Or is this integral just defined to be some type of area of the image of f? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a change of coordinates in the plane, $(x,y) \to (u,v)$, then the area element $dudv = J(x,y)dxdy$ where $J(x,y)$ is the (absolute value of the) determinant of the Jacobian matrix with entries $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac {\partial v}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$ so the formula is $dudv=|\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}\frac {\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}|dxdy$.

In the case the map is given by an (injective) analytic function $f=u+iv$ the C-R equations imply that $dudv=[(\frac {\partial u}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2]dxdy=|f'(z)|^2dxdy$ where $z=x+iy$

(as $f'(z)=\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$ by C-R)

So if now $f=u+iv$ is analytic univalent mapping the unit disc $D$ onto some domain $U$, the area of $U$ is given by definition as $\int\int_U 1 dudv=\int\int_D |f'(z)|^2dxdy$ by the above.

If now $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ using polar coordinates, one immediately gets that the area of $U$ is $\pi \sum_{n \ge 1}n|a_n|^2$

Comment: since f is analytic on its domain we know there is a power series expansion of f at each point in the domain. What let you say that f is a single power series centered at 0 everywhere? Wouldnt we have to consider the power series of f centered at z_0 where z_0 runs over the domain D?

Comment: Of course there is a power series centered at any point $z_0$ in the unit disc with radius of convergence (at least) $1-|z_0|$ but the one centered at zero covers the whole disc since it's radius of convergence is at least one, so it is convenient to express the result in terms of it's coefficients

Comment: By polar coordinates do you mean changing (x,y) to (r,$\theta$) so that dxdy=r dr d$\theta$? In that case how do we perform this integration as you say we can? Because f(D) is the only region we have and there’s no bounds of integration or explicit forms of z^n here? Or by polar coordinates do you mean represent the complex z by their polar form re^i$\theta$?

Comment: Oh thank you for the explanation on the power series representation

Comment: The integration is on the disc of $|f'|^2$ so one uses $dxdy=rdrd\theta$; note that $|f'|^2=f'\bar f'$ so if you substitute $f'=\sum na_nz^{n-1}$ and the corresponding conjugate and multiply term by term (allowed by absolute and locally uniform convergence), the integral has diagonal terms that are only in $r=|z|$ and non diagonal terms that cancel when integrated against theta by periodicity; the remaining $r$ integral is then straightforward

Comment: Ok so I’m not putting any bounds of integration, just leaving f(D) as the region in general and making the coordinate swap dxdy=rdrd$\theta$. I have written out both f’ and it’s conjugate and started multiplying terms. I have a bunch of terms that are not just |z|=z$\bar{z}$ - ones that contain |z| times either z or it’s conjugate raised to some power. At this point, if I swap the integrals from drd$\theta$ = d$\theta$dr and evaluate with respect to d$\theta$ first, how does periodicity cancel anything? And there’s still the problem of how to evaluate in d$\theta$ when We are in z?

Comment: my apologies for not understanding too clearly, this graduate course is my first exposure to complex analysis but the professor expects an undergraduate background so he doesn’t stop to explain how to use a lot of the introductory ideas

Comment: $dxdy$ are the coordinates on the unit disc  -by definition the area is integral of one on the image domain and we change variables back to the unit disc precisely to control the bounds; the price is that now the integrand is not one anymore but $|f'(z)|^2$ - so the bounds are $0 \le r \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$ and any non diagonal term has a factor $e^{ik\theta}$ for some non zero integer $k$ which integrates to zero on a full period

Comment: Ok one last understanding question because I think I have understood the rest and its pretty quick - how do we know that the radius of convergence of our power series centered at 0 is at least 1? Is it by Hadamard Criterion somehow? I have proven that if the coefficients of a power series centered at 0 form a bounded sequence then the radius of convergence is at least one however I am not sure we can conclude our power series here has coefficients that form a bounded sequence?

Comment: if a function is analytic in a disc, the radius of convergence of its Taylor series at the center of the disc is at least the radius of the disc - in other words, if like here the function is analytic in the unit disc, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at the origin is at least $1$ - this follows easily from Cauchy for example by expanding the integral into a power series, or one can argue by contradiction (a power series with radius exactly $R$ must have a singularity on the circle of radius $R$);

Answer (score 2):

You have a holomorphic bijective function $f \colon B(0, 1) \to f(B(0, 1)) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, where $B(0, 1)$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You want the "area" of $f(B(0, 1))$. In this case you probably want the ordinary Lebesgue measure of $f(B(0, 1))$ which is given by integrating $1$ over $f(B(0, 1))$:
$$m(f(B(0, 1))) = \int_{f(B(0, 1))}1\,dy.$$
Now we can do a change of variables $y = f(x)$, $dy = |\det(Df(x))|\,dx$. If $f'(x) = a + ib$, then $$Df(x) = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus $|\det(Df(x))| = a^2 + b^2 = |f'(x)|^2$. Thus
$$m(f(B(0, 1))) = \int_{B(0, 1)}|f'(x)|^2\,dx.$$

Comment: note that if $f$ is holomorphic and injective, its image is automatically open and its inverse is automatically holomorphic, while $|\det(Df(x))| = |f'(x)|^2$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the corrections.